# Subquery in SELECT clause and solve "subquery returns more than one row"

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

Desired output:

```
2014-11-12 2 
2014-11-18 2 
2014-11-23 1
```

My code:

```
SELECT Attendance.Attend_Date, (SELECT COUNT(Attendance.AttendDet_Type) as P 
FROM Student, Attendance 
WHERE Student.Stud_ID = Attendance.Stud_ID 
AND Student.Stud_Class = '1A1' 
AND Attendance.Attend_Date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-01' 
AND Attendance.AttendDet_Type = 'P' 
GROUP BY Attendance.Attend_Date
) as T
FROM Student, Attendance
WHERE Student.Stud_ID = Attendance.Stud_ID
AND Student.Stud_Class = '1A1'
AND Attendance.Attend_Date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-01'
GROUP BY Attendance.Attend_Date
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: You probably don't mean to have the GROUP BY in your sub-select? (This is why formatting is important)

Comment: I love it when people provide a desired output based upon no input.

Answer (score 0):

My answers. Thanks guys!

```
SELECT Attendance.Attend_Date, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN Attendance.AttendDet_Type = 'P' THEN Attendance.Attend_Date ELSE null END)AS P, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN Attendance.AttendDet_Type = 'A' THEN Attendance.Attend_Date ELSE null END)AS A, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN Attendance.AttendDet_Type = 'C' THEN Attendance.Attend_Date ELSE null END)AS C, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN Attendance.AttendDet_Type = 'MC' THEN Attendance.Attend_Date ELSE null END)AS MC 
FROM Student, Attendance 
WHERE Student.Stud_ID = Attendance.Stud_ID 
AND Student.Stud_Class = '" & DropDownList13.SelectedValue & "' 
AND Attendance.Attend_Date BETWEEN '" & Label5.Text & "' 
AND '" & Label6.Text & "' 
GROUP BY Attendance.Attend_Date
```